WebSocket: The URL 'wss://localhost:undefined/_nuxt/' is invalid
I made changes to the NGINX config and made changes to nuxt.config.ts
My application is running at /backoffice
nginx.conf
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:880 ssl http2;

    server_name example.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.key;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location ~ /_nuxt {
        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000;  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # My application is running at /backoffice
    location /backoffice {
        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000;  
    }
    
   # php page
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}


nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      title: 'BackOffice',
    },
  },

  devtools: {
    enabled: true,
  },

  vite: {
    define: { 'process.env': {} },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('.', import.meta.url)),
        '@core': fileURLToPath(new URL('./@core', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
  },

  hooks: {
    'vite:extendConfig'(viteInlineConfig) {
      viteInlineConfig.server = {
        ...viteInlineConfig.server,
      };
    },
  },

})

package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt dev --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3000",
    "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.mjs build",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "start": "HOST=127.0.0.1 PORT=3000  node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nitropack": "^2.9.6",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
  
  },
  "devDependencies": {,
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^3.1.1",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.11.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.11",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "1.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.8",
  },
}


But I get messages in the browser console on the page /backoffice

WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.domain.com/_nuxt/' failed:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'wss://localhost:undefined/_nuxt/' is invalid.

How can I fix the config to fix the error?
I tried to change the nuxt.config.ts.
I was adding a section
  hooks: {
    'vite:extendConfig'(viteInlineConfig) {
      viteInlineConfig.server = {
        ...viteInlineConfig.server,
      hmr: {
         protocol: 'wss',
         clientPort: 443,
      };
    },
  },

But it didn't give any results.

Try a different port than the standard ssl port, try client port 8001

I checked the operation under the configuration hmr: {protocol: 'wss', clientPort: 8001}  , the error text has changed to WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.domain.com:8001/_nuxt/' failed: 
